# Query and QueryMap not working for Rest API

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit2.

Rest Api - https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1

**Code -**

```
Call<Root> call = apiEndpoints.getData(1,2);

call.enqueue(new Callback<Root>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Root> call, Response<Root> response) {


        if(!response.isSuccessful())
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Unsuccessful response!");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.body().getData().size());

        List<Data> list = response.body().getData();
        for(Data d : list)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+d.getEmail());
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Root> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: There're failure!"+t.getMessage());

    }
});
```

API service interface -

```
public interface ApiEndpoints {

    @GET("users")
    Call<Root> getData(@Query("page") Integer... page);
}
```

Output -

```
onResponse : 6

onResponse : george@email.com
onResponse : bob@email.com
onResponse : korn@email.com
onResponse : lorry@email.com
onResponse : gord@email.com
onResponse : mike@email.com
```

Expected output :

> Since one page contains 6 records, the output size should be 12 when
> querying 2 pages. And There should be 12 emails fetched from the 2
> pages. The output i am getting is of page 1

I am wondering if there's some problem with this API?

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

this [request](https://reqres.in/api/users) have two parameter for fetch data:

1. page: page number (default is 1)
2. per_page: number of record in page (default is 6)

if you want fetch 12 record , you must send per_page parameter to server:

https://reqres.in/api/users (return 6 record from page 1)

https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1 (return 6 record from page 1)

https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2&per_page=6 (return 6 record from page 2)

https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1&per_page=12 (return 12 record from page 1)

https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2&per_page=12 (return 12 record from page 2 but result is empty because all user count is 12)

then :

```
Call<Root> getData(@Query("page") Integer page,@Query("per_page") Integer per_page);
```

and :

```
Call<Root> call = apiEndpoints.getData(1,12);
```